# Obter código HTML externo Renderizado

Tags: php, javascript, html, codeigniter, highcharts

Estou montando um PDF e nesse PDF tenho que colocar um gráfico que está sendo feito pelo `Highcharts`. Criei um código HTML e JS montando o gráfico e ele está criando certinho, o problema é que preciso obter o código HTML desse gráfico renderizado e quando faço a requisição no link da página que monta o gráfico, ele traz o HTML não renderizado, ou seja, sem ter executado o JS para montar o gráfico.

```
<?php

public function SendRequest($url){

        $curl_handle=curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        $query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
        curl_close($curl_handle);

        return $query;
}

public function cria_grafico($id_pedido, $id_produto){

     echo $this->load->view('sellins/GeraGraficoSellinB4', array('id_pedido'=>$id_pedido, 'id_produto'=>$id_produto), TRUE);

}

public function download($codigo_pedido = false){

$grafico = $this->SendRequest(base_url('Sellin_B4/cria_grafico/'.$produto['idPedido'].'/'.$produto['codigoProduto']));

$file = 'uploads/extract_sellin_goagro_'.time().'.pdf';

$mpdf = new mPDF();

$mpdf->SetHeader('Go Agro - Extract Sellin');

$mpdf->writeHTML($grafico);

$mpdf->SetFooter('{PAGENO}');

$mpdf->Output($file, 'F');

}
```

No método **cria_grafico** é onde ele chama o HTML com JS e monta o gráfico. Se eu acessar o link meusite.com.br/cria_grafico ele mostra o gráfico renderizado, mas quando faço uma requisição para obter o mesmo resultado via código, ele traz o HTML sem ser renderizado.

Answer (score 1):

Você não vai conseguir realizar o que deseja porque o Javascript é executado SOMENTE na máquina do cliente pelo navegador Web, após o cliente receber o conteúdo (e se o Javascript estiver habilitado).

Mesmo quando você tenta fazer uma requisição por dentro com cURL, ele monta tudo e até posta o código correto, por isso quando você acessa, você enxerga corretamente porque vê do seu navegador. Mas internamente a requisição está em âmbito do servidor Web, que ao mesclar a view no PDF não interpreta o código Javascript que verdadeiramente monta o gráfico.

Experimente utilizar uma biblioteca geradora de gráficos que emprega apenas CSS. São em geral menos bonitas e não-interativas, mas atendem à situações como esta.